# google-style autocompletion tutorial/example

Tags: forms, autocomplete

I have an app that would benefit from google-style autocompletion while filling in an entry field.

Any pointers on how this is implemented, or a package that I can drop in to assist?

Comment: if it's google-style in the browser, then the only choice is javascript, right?

Comment: Or do you mean, what language for the backend?

Comment: nodejs api for magic autocomplete: https://gist.github.com/4105774

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I use [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) and the [Autocomplete plug-in](http://www.pengoworks.com/workshop/jquery/autocomplete.htm) for this. It allows the data to be either specified in an JavaScript array locally, or received via the network, if a suitable data provider is written.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a decent tutorial using jQuery for the ajax http://nodstrum.com/2007/09/19/autocompleter/

Answer (score 1):

I use [script.aculo.us autocompletion](http://demo.script.aculo.us/ajax/autocompleter_customized). The demo is in Rails but i use it with PHP.

Answer (score 1):

Nowadays jQueryUI is a great choice:

http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/

Answer (score 1):

If You want do it Yourself without jQuery just change the .pac-container like below:

```
 { width:280px !important; font-family:Tahoma;}
```

or visit this site: http://benkammerling.wordpress.com/2012/02/17/google-maps-places-autocomplete-styling-in-css/

Think help U.